# If one disc is rotating in air, and another disc is very gently placed over it, what would be the change in state of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am having lot of questions on this concept.
(There is friction between the two discs)
In what direction would friction be there and what would be the direction of rotation of the disc placed on the first disc? What would be the change in the angular velocities. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

According to Newton's third law each disc would exert a force on the other disc and hence a torque on the other disc because of friction acing between the two discs.
The direction of the frictional forces would be such as to oppose and hence reduce the relative movement between the discs i.e. the initially stationary disc would start to speed up and the other disc would slow down until the discs were rotating at the same speed.
If there were no external torques acting on the system of two discs then all the angular momentum that the spinning disc had initially would be shared between the two discs at the end because angular momentum is conserved.
There would be a decrease in the rotational kinetic energy of the system because of the frictional forces converting the rotational kinetic energy into heat.

Comment: Why would the initial stationary disc speed up and the other disc would slow down? If the initial rotating disc is rotating anti-clockwise, then could you please tell the direction of friction more specifically? And, in what case of friction  would there be slipping (i.e. they would not spin with same angular velocity) ?

Comment: When the discs come into contact there is relative motion between them so the frictional forces will act so as to reduce that relative motion.  On the disc which is spinning the frictional force will be in the opposite direction to the direction of spin and the disc which initially was not spinning would have a frictional  force on it in the same direction as the spinning disc.  Once the two discs rotate at the same speed in the same direction there is no need for a frictional force as there is no relative movement between the two discs.